# ZeroMQ library linking: undefined reference to symbol, error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line

Tags: compiling, libraries, shared-library

When compiling a simple c++ file that uses ZeroMQ, I get:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccbHbSAY.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev@@GLIBCXX_3.4'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

which I think is trying to tell me that I'm calling a symbol that does not exist in the shared library that I'm linking. Here's my compiling command:

```
gcc -Wall -I/usr/local/include zeromq_worker.cpp /usr/local/lib/libzmq.so.5.0.2
```

I tried with `libzqm.so` and `libzmq.so.5`, which are also in `/usr/local/lib`, but the same error occurs

Also, `_ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev@@GLIBCXX_3.4` is the compiled name for some structure. Which is it? I think it can help understanding where the error comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `g++` not `gcc` if it's a C++ file.

Also it's not usual to explicitly specify a library that way: normally you should give a link directive like `-lzmq` preceded if necessary by a library search path directive of the form `-L /usr/local/lib`.

So try

```
g++ -Wall -I /usr/local/include zeromq_worker.cpp -L /usr/local/lib -lzmq
```